# Crash of application while debugging when Textbox is empty

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to create a Textbox, whose text changes color dynamically from black to red when a value larger than a number is typed, and vice versa. I managed to do this but when I erase all the content of the textbox, my debugging application crashes with the error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'` Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If CDbl(TextBox1.Text) > CDbl(Label2.Text) Then
        TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
    If CDbl(TextBox1.Text) = CDbl(Label2.Text) Then
        TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
    If CDbl(TextBox1.Text) < CDbl(Label2.Text) Then
        TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
End Sub
```

Which feature do I have to add in order to prevent the crashing of my application? Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Comment: Well, to get you started, move the last `If` to the beginning and make the remaining `If`s to `ElseIf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues that may require attention.

The VB casting functions like `CInt`, `CDbl` etc. will throw an exception if casting fails. An empty value does not represent a numerical value, so it will fail. A solution might be to check for empty string values first.

You also might want to use an `If ... ElseIf ... ElseIf ... ElseIf ... EndIf` construct to avoid execution of subsequent if-blocks once you executed a matching if-block.

But then the code would crash if you would type a non-numeric value, like "A"...

So I would propose to use the [`Double.TryParse` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse) instead of `CDbl` here.

Also notice that you normally want to use black as the default foreground color, but only want to switch to red if the value of the textbox is larger than the value of the label. Why not just express that literally in code?

So here are my two cents, using a variable `NewForeColor` that is initially set to `Color.Black`. It is then only set to `Color.Red` if both the textbox and the label hold a numerical value and the textbox value is larger than the label value. Eventually the textbox's foreground color is set to the value of the `NewForeColor` variable:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim NewForeColor As Color = Color.Black
    Dim TextBox1Value As Double
    Dim Label2Value As Double

    If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, TextBox1Value) AndAlso Double.TryParse(Label2.Text, Label2Value) Then
        If TextBox1Value > Label2Value Then
            NewForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End If

    TextBox1.ForeColor = NewForeColor
End Sub
```